# Implementing fraction simplification in a fraction class

Tags: c++, function, class, operator-overloading, output

so I've been working on this class for a couple days. and the whole program is compiling nicely, except for that I really am not sure how to implement my simplification

```
fraction& simplify(const fraction& fr)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    if(fr.Numerator>fr.Denominator)
    {
    a = fr.Numerator;
    b = fr.Denominator;
    }
    else if (fr.Numerator<fr.Denominator)
    {
        a = fr.Denominator;
        b = fr.Numerator;
    }
    else
    {
        a=fr.Numerator;
        fraction simplified(fr.Numerator/a,fr.Denominator/a);
        return simplified;
    }
    {
    while((b)!=0)
        {
            c=(a%b);
            a=b;
            b=c;
        };
    }
    fraction simplified(fr.Numerator/a,fr.Denominator/a);
    return simplified;
}
```

I wanted to have it run in my output function

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const fraction& fr)
{
    simplify(fr);
    if(fr.Denominator==1||fr.Numerator==0)
        stream << fr.Numerator;
    else if(fr.Numerator>fr.Denominator)
    {
        cout << fr.Numerator/fr.Denominator << '+' << fr.Numerator%fr.Denominator << '/' << fr.Denominator;
    }
    else
    stream << fr.Numerator << '/' << fr.Denominator;
    return stream;
}
```

and that has resulted in nothing happening. as far as I can tell it's because the fraction is a const, but the compiler is very displeased with me if the ostream's argument isn't a const. how should I go about implementing this?

Comment: Unrelated: You're not going to like the results of returning a reference to an automatic variable.

Comment: You pass a reference to simplify but never modify it. Try `fr = simplify(fr);`

Comment: @WhozCraig so should I be modifying the simplifier to not return a reference? what should it be manipulating?

JohnnyMopp that doesn't work, I assume because fr is const. I feel like I'm just manipulating the wrong thing

Comment: Then you can create a temp fraction: `fraction frToPrint = simplify(fr);` and use that in the rest of the function.

Comment: Do you want `simplify` to modify its argument ('fr') or not?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp there's the obvious answer I should have seen. thank you that works

Comment: For what it's worth, the `if` statements above are needless. Euclid's algorithm for the GCD already handles all the `a > b`, `a < b` and `a == b` cases just fine.

Comment: I thought it had to be big%small?

Comment: @Ggnome As written originally you should return a by-value copy and assign the result back to `fr` (or some other variable that is ultimately dumped to the output stream). Alternatively you could skip the result entirely and just modify `fr` by non-const reference. In short the way you're doing this is a little odd. It didn't matter in your original code because frankly you weren't using it (which was a problem), but it matters now with the accepted answer. The return value should be by-val and rely on RVO for proper optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should catch the result of simply in operator overloaded function to some temp variable as fr is const so don't do

```
fr=simplify(fr);
```

and use the properties of that object instead of fr